# Flutter Printing Package: Create pdf table with loop

Tags: pdf, flutter, printing

I want to create a pdf document with the package 'pdf'. The example on the dart - page is working fine: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf#-example-tab-

You can see that the table is static. I want to create a dynamic table in the pdf document.

The columns will be constant, but the rows have to be dynamic.

I have tried to insert a for() - loop.

The syntax is not correct.

```
      pdfWidget.Table.fromTextArray(context: context, data: <List<String>> [
        <String>['Date', 'PDF Version', 'Acrobat Version'],
        //.....
        //more Strings here.....
      ]),
```

Comment: I solved the issue. Does anyone want to know the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue.
This seemed to work for me.

```
pdf.addPage(
  MultiPage(
    build: (context) => [
      Table.fromTextArray(context: context, data: <List<String>>[
        <String>['Msg ID', 'DateTime', 'Type', 'Body'],
        ...msgList.map(
            (msg) => [msg.counter, msg.dateTimeStamp, msg.type, msg.body])
      ]),
    ],
  ),
);
```

where my `msgList` object was a custom List, ie: `List<SingleMessage>`

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do it, I prefer to fill the List separately, like:

```
List<List<String>> salidas = new List();
salidas.add(<String>['Title1','Title2', ... , 'Title n']);

for(var indice=0;indice<records.length;indice++) {
   List<String> recind = <String>[
       records[indice].Stringfield1,
       records[indice].Stringfield2,
       ...,
       records[indice].Stringfieldn
   ];
   salidas.add(recind);
}
...
fpdf.Table.fromTextArray(context: context,data: salidas),
```

Comment: It is showing me error I am not able to add recind to salidas as salidas showing error
"the arugment type Map<String,Dynamic> can't be assigned to the parameter type List<String>

Comment: @kritisharma: I am sorry, I made a mistake. I just edit the code, this has to work

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the table is so long as to span several pages.